# How to get player's spawn point in fabric mod?

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

How to get player's spawn point? Or bed position? I tried to use `findRespawnPosition`, but i haven't `ServerWorld` parameter, only World, tried getSleepingPosition, but it returns `Optional<BlockPos>`. I using the `TypedActionResult` method: `public TypedActionResult<ItemStack> use(World world, PlayerEntity playerEntity, Hand hand)` How can i do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.